# Not able to return Object array from asynchronous mongo db query in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update the array of object 'associativeArray' using a mongo db query  & want to return it to next then block so.
But when I run the application I get old values in the array.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

var error_imports = require('../models/models.js').errorimport;
var users = require('../models/models.js').users;
var magento_categories = require('../models/models.js').magentocategories;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb');

var allprodsArray = error_imports.find({sku_number:"889059223895-AllSaints"});
var allCategoriesArray = magento_categories.find();
//var allproducts = [];
var allCategories = [];
var mainCategories = [];
var pro = [];
var name = "Sagar";
var collectionOne = [];

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var allprodsArray = error_imports.find().limit(10);
    var allproducts = [];
    var products = [];

    allprodsArray.exec(function(err,prods){
        if(err)
            return cosole.log(err);
        prods.forEach(function(prod){
            var elem = new Object();
            elem["id"] = prod._id
            elem["tags"] = prod.id;

            allproducts.push(elem);
            pro = allproducts;

        });
    res.render('index.html',{products:pro});
    });
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var allprodsArray_1 = error_imports.find().limit(10);
    var suffix_1,
        suffix_2,
        suffix_3,
        suffix_4;

    var associativeArray = new Object();
    var ass = [];
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    var mag_cat_query;

    allprodsArray_1.exec(function(err,prods1){
        if(err)
            return cosole.log(err);
        prods1.forEach(function(prod1){
            var selectedCategory = '';
            var id = prod1._id;
            suffix_1 = 'statessource_' + id;
            suffix_2 = 'citiessource_' + id;
            suffix_3 = 'city_' + id;
            suffix_4 = 'area_' + id;

            if(req.body[suffix_1]!=null){
                selectedCategory = selectedCategory +'/'+ req.body[suffix_1];
                if(req.body[suffix_2]!=null){
                    selectedCategory = selectedCategory +'/'+ req.body[suffix_2];
                    if(req.body[suffix_3]!=null){
                        selectedCategory = selectedCategory +'/'+req.body[suffix_3];
                        if(req.body[suffix_4]!=null){
                            selectedCategory = selectedCategory +'/'+req.body[suffix_4];
                        }
                    }
                }
                selectedCategory = selectedCategory.slice(0,-1);
                console.log("Selected category :"+ selectedCategory);
                associativeArray[id] = selectedCategory;                ///inserting values to array
                var mag_cat_query =  magento_categories.find({"categories":selectedCategory});

            }
        });

        //updating values of array depends on query results
         for(prop in associativeArray)
    {
        magento_categories.find({"categories":associativeArray[prop]}).exec(function(err,cat){
                if(err)
                    return cosole.log(err);
                cat.forEach(function(c){
                    console.log("PPPPPPPPPP:  "+c.parent_category_ids);
                    associativeArray[prop] = c.parent_category_ids;
                    console.log("p id: "+prop+" Category::  "+associativeArray[prop]);

                });
                 return associativeArray;
            });

    }
        return associativeArray;
    }).then(function(ass){
        console.log("In then");
        for(property in associativeArray){
            console.log("IDDDD "+property+"  Category: "+associativeArray[property]);
        }
        res.render('index.html',{products:pro});

    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you return associativeArray from within mag_cat_query.exec(function(err,cat){}); after cat.forEach is done?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you return return `associativeArray` from within `mag_cat_query.exec`?

```
for(prop in associativeArray) {
  mag_cat_query.exec(function(err,cat){
    if(err)
      return cosole.log(err);

      cat.forEach(function(c){
         console.log("PPPPPPPPPP:  "+c.parent_category_ids);
         associativeArray[id] = c.parent_category_ids;
         console.log("p id: "+id+" Category::  "+associativeArray[id]);
      });

      return associativeArray;
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution but its not working. Node is updating the array values after execution of then() block.